# How to refresh the previous selection values of parameters in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho

I created a report in pentaho report designer , in that i am using three filters .
  My problem is once i select one filter it showing results perfectly,when i am select the second filter it show the results with first filter selection and same applicable for third filter also .why because previous selection values still appearing after selection of second or third filter also. 
  My requirement is when i am selected a filter i want to show that filter results only.
  is it possible please provide a solution to me ,Thank you in advance .

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a query for get parameter values , you have to write condition in where clause like this. 
 `WHERE gustoreid IN (SELECT CASE WHEN('${storeid}' = 'All' OR '${storeid}' IS NULL) THEN gustoreid ELSE '${storeid}'  END)`

 Then when you select second filter or third filter  make sure the privious filter's value is "All". then you can get 3rd filter values only .